# Get Word on position x using custom separator

Tags: sql-server

Using SQL Server, how do I split a stringand access item x using separator y?

Take a string "Hello, how are you?". 
position 1 split by ',' return "Hello"
position 1 split by ' ' return "Hello,"

Thanks!

Comment: which version of sql server?in sql server 2016 there is a function named STRING_SPLIT, in other versions of sql server you should to define a table valued function for this purpose

Comment: Sql 2012. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (
        @List NVARCHAR(MAX),
        @Delim VARCHAR(255)
    )
    RETURNS TABLE
    AS
        RETURN ( SELECT [Value] FROM 
          ( 
            SELECT 
              [Value] = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@List, [Number],
              CHARINDEX(@Delim, @List + @Delim, [Number]) - [Number])))
            FROM (SELECT Number = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name)
              FROM sys.all_objects) AS x
              WHERE Number <= LEN(@List)
              AND SUBSTRING(@Delim + @List, [Number], LEN(@Delim)) = @Delim
          ) AS y
        );
```